# Enter into docker container after shell script execution is complete

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

If I want to execute one shell script as ENTRYPOINT and enter into docker container when shell script execution is complete.

My Dockerfile has following lines at the end:

```
WORKDIR artifacts
ENTRYPOINT ./my_shell.sh
```

When I run it with following command, it executes shell script but doesn't enter into docker container.

```
docker run -it testub /bin/bash
```

Can someone please let me know if I am missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that control what a container runs when it starts, the entrypoint (`ENTRYPOINT`) and the command (`CMD`). They follow the following logic:

- If the entrypoint is defined, then it is run with the value for the command included as additional arguments.
- If the entrypoint is not defined, then the command is run by itself.

You can override one or both of the values defined in the image. `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh testub` would run /bin/sh instead of `./my_shell.sh`, overriding the entrypoint. And `docker run -it testub /bin/bash` will override the command, making the container start with `./my_shell.sh /bin/bash`.

The quick answer is to run `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash testub` and from there, kick off your `./my_shell.sh`. A better solution is to update `./my_shell.sh` to check for any additional parameters and run them with the following at the end of the script:

```
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  exec "$@"
fi
```

Comment: I tried with `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh testub`. I was able to enter into container but it dint run shell script which I have mentioned as ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile

Comment: Yes, see the last paragraph. You can't run two commands as your entrypoint, but you can run a shell and then kick off your script in that shell. Or from your script, you can kick off a shell which was described at the very end.

Comment: So I have to run the shell script after entering into container. There is no way I can run it first with `docker run` and then enter into container?

Comment: When the command you run exits, so does the container and the only option at that point is to restart the same command that was run before. If the container hasn't exited, you can `docker exec` to run a command in the running container. But again, I gave you the 3 lines you need to include at the end of your `my_shell.sh`, why do you decline that option?

Comment: I am confused a bit with the lines to be added at the end in my_shell.sh, will those lines make docker container alive and enter into it rather than exiting from container? Because my ultimate goal is to enter into container and let users execute whatever they want to execute, shell script is just for basic common setup which I want to execute with `docker run` rather than being executed by the user.